# Not getting full objects details with ng-model when using ng-options

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have an property cardDetails which have an array of objects

```
var cardDetails = [{
            "cardHolderName":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "cardNumber" :'1234'
            "mobileNumber":"91098765678",
            "cardType":"C",
            "cardStatus":0,
            "created":1449572395000,
            "updated":1449572395000
            }]
```

In my html I am using ng-options to populate

```
<select ng-change="" ng-model="payment.card" ng-options="card.cardType as (card.cardType==='C' ? 'Credit Card':'Debit Card') +' - XXXX XXXX XXXX '+card.cardNumber for card in cardList">
```

I am retrieving the selected drop down in my controller like below

```
paymentCard = $scope.payment.card;
```

The value I am getting is only C which is card type, but I want all the Values of selected object. But If I use ng-options like below I get the whole Object

```
<select ng-change="" ng-model="payment.card" ng-options="card.cardType for card in cardList">
```

My objective is to show customized relevant information to user while I want to get other fields in the back end. Any Idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Update your html, this is full example:

in the ng-options you can get all or one of params in your object, when you set "card.cardType" you will get just "cardType" but if you set "card" you will get all of your object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ExampleController">

<head>
  <title>stackoverflow</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <select ng-model="payment.card" ng-options="card as card.cardNumber for card in cardDetails"></select>
  {{payment.card}}

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module("app", [])
      .controller("ExampleController", ["$scope",
        function($scope) {
          $scope.cardDetails = [{
            "cardHolderName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "cardNumber": "1234",
            "mobileNumber": "91098765678",
            "cardType": "C",
            "cardStatus": 0,
            "created": 1449572395000,
            "updated": 1449572395000
          }];
        }
      ])
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Maher, with the code if you can tell him what he is missing, it would be great. :)

Comment: @RumeshEranga Hi, sure i will edit my answer, thank to you my friend.